# is not a member of ASP.masterpage_master

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created my own MasterPage called MyMasterPage.master.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" Inherits="AMasterPage" CodeBehind="MyMasterPage.master.vb" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

In the code behind MyMasterPage.master.vb I have added this which matches the Inherits in my MasterPage.master file

```
Partial Class AMasterPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

I also have set a public property in my codebehind

```
Public Property MyProperty() As String
    Get
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_myProperty) Then
            _myProperty = "a property"
        End If
        Return _myProperty 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _myProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

When I try to access the code behind property from my MyMasterPage.master file like this

```
<%=Me.MyProperty%>
```

I get the error 'MyProperty' is not a member of ASP.masterpage_master

Comment: It actually is a different name. I just changed it to property to make it more general.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project before running it?

Comment: Yes I did clean project and rebuild project. The errors show up when I try to rebuild the project

Comment: Are you missing a namespace in your `Inherits` attribute?  What's your root namespace in project properties?

Comment: Your `CodeBehind` declaration does not match your class name.

Comment: @Mark If I put the root namespace in the Inherits like 'Inherits="RootNamespace.AMasterPage"' I will get the error 'RootNamespace.AMasterPage' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

Comment: @OneFineDay My Partial Class in the code behind matches the inherits AMasterPage. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good answer.  It might be horrifically bad:

for VB.net:

dim session as mySession = master.GetType().GetMethod("getMySession").Invoke(master, obj)

although, you might want to swap my GetMethod with GetProperty: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_System_Type_
as your trying to get a property instead